# Fastest way to sort an array by timestamp

Tags: javascript, sorting, timestamp

how can i sort this array by timestamp and what is the fastest way (array has many many entries)?

**my array**

```
  myList = new Array();

  myList[0]               = {};
  myList[0]['title']      = 'I am really new';
  myList[0]['timestamp']  = 1317039046;
  myList[0]['date']       = '2011-09-26T12:10:46+00:00'; 

  myList[1]               = {};
  myList[1]['title']      = 'I am the oldest';
  myList[1]['timestamp']  = 1315656646;
  myList[1]['date']       = '2011-09-10T12:10:46+00:00';

  myList[2]               = {};
  myList[2]['title']      = 'I am older';
  myList[2]['timestamp']  = 1316866246;
  myList[2]['date']       = '2011-09-24T12:10:46+00:00';

  myList[3]               = {};
  myList[3]['title']      = 'I am old';
  myList[3]['timestamp']  = 1316952646;
  myList[3]['date']       = '2011-09-25T12:10:46+00:00';
```

**example**
http://jsbin.com/ejagup/2/edit#preview

Comment: Fyi, you can use `myList = [];` and, if you don't want a global var, prefix it with `var`: `var myList = [];`

Answer (score 139, accepted):

```
myList.sort(function(x, y){
    return x.timestamp - y.timestamp;
})
```

`myList` is a JavaScript array, which supports the `sort` method. This method accepts a function as argument, which sorts the array according to the returned value.

Currently, the sort algorithm will place the element with the lowest timestamp first. Swap `x.timestamp` and `y.timestamp` if you want to sort the array in the other direction.

Comment: OP didn't ask, but the `sort` method can also sort by date  -- he only needs to convert the strings into `Date` objects before subtracting them -- http://jsbin.com/ejagup/4/edit

Comment: @Blazemonger's comment saved me a lot of hassle

Comment: @Blazemonger for those using TypeScript, you have to add ````.getTime()````, e.g. ````return date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()````

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to sort an array by date in JavaScript,
Here is an example of how this method of sorting an array by date in JavaScript looks

```
 const fetchMessageData = () => {

        return (
            AllMessagesArr.sort((x, y) => {
                return new Date(x.timestamp) < new Date(y.timestamp) ? 1 : -1
            })
        ).reverse()
    }

         console.log("Display messages in Ascending order" ,fetchMessageData())
```

*Sort the array on basis of timestamp*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).