# How to sort array of dates in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, sorting, date

I have an array of dates as below:

```
var unavailableDates = ["31-5-2014", "1-6-2014", "2-6-2014", "3-6-2014", "26-5-2014", "27-5-2014", "28-5-2014", "29-5-2014"];
```

How can I sort this array without changing the date format?

Comment: If you store them as year first, it'd be simple.  Can you translate it to that format or simply change the code that returns this array?

Comment: This is similar to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002848/how-to-define-custom-sort-function-in-javascript

Comment: @iamdev will it work for dates ?

Comment: You would have to specify in your custom sort function (that you write) how you want it to compare 2 strings.  Then it will go through using those rules and sort the list.  I'm pretty sure it's the only way in your case.

Comment: Have a look at :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555025/jquery-fastest-way-to-sort-an-array-by-timestamp

Comment: You can find some useful answers to this topic here: **[Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759350/2247494)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it would be work for you, try this code

```
  var unavailableDates = ["31-5-2014", "1-6-2014", "2-6-2014", 
              "3-6-2014", "26-5-2014", "27-5-2014", "28-5-2014", "29-5-2014"];
    function SortByDate(a, b){
       var amyDate = a.split("-");
       var aNewDate=new Date(amyDate[1]+","+amyDate[0]+","+amyDate[2]).getTime();
       var bmyDate = b.split("-");
       var bNewDate=new Date(bmyDate[1]+","+bmyDate[0]+","+bmyDate[2]).getTime();
       return ((aNewDate < bNewDate) ? -1 : ((aNewDate > bNewDate) ? 1 : 0));
    }
    console.log(unavailableDates.sort(SortByDate));
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/77mgM/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Code speak for itself.

```
var unavailableDates = ["31-5-2014", "1-6-2014", "2-6-2014", "3-6-2014", "26-5-2014", "27-5-2014", "28-5-2014", "29-5-2014"];
unavailableDates = unavailableDates
    .map(function (val, idx) {
        var arr = val.split('-');
        return new Date(arr[2], arr[1] - 1, arr[0]);
    })
    .sort(function (x, y) {
        return x > y
    });
console.log(unavailableDates);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/TNPN5/1/)

Comment: @LeoTAbraham the `Date` object's months are 0 based. You'd have to do `arr[1]-1`.

Comment: I have already tried it. But right now, June 2 is coming first http://jsfiddle.net/jXP5D/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var eventDates = ["31-5-2014", "1-6-2014", "2-6-2014", "3-6-2014", "26-5-2014", "27-5-2014", "28-5-2014", "29-5-2014"];
           
var result = data.sort(function (a, b){ new Date(a.eventDates).getTime() - new Date(b.eventDates).getTime()
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Typo: `data.sort` should be `eventDates.sort`

Answer (score 0):

This alternative should work fine and does not change the date format at all. The sort function uses date format `YYYYMMDD` just for sorting only but leaves the original dates intact.

```
var unavailableDates = ["31-5-2014", "1-6-2014", "2-6-2014", "3-6-2014", "26-5-2014", "27-5-2014", "28-5-2014", "29-5-2014"];
unavailableDates.sort(function( a, b ) {
    var sA = a.split( '-' ).map(function(v,i) { return (i<2)?("0"+v).substr(-2):v; }).reverse().join(''); 
    var sB = b.split( '-' ).map(function(v,i) { return (i<2)?("0"+v).substr(-2):v; }).reverse().join('');
    return sA > sB;
})
console.log( unavailableDates );
```

[JS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LMqLb/1/)