# How to Sort a Javascript Unix Timestamp Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, unix

I have a Array Containing Unix time stamps and i want to sort that array any one know how to do it? or maybe converting it to simple date format and then sorting them any way?

Please also give example

I have tried this but didn't work [Jquery - Fastest way to sort an array by timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555025/jquery-fastest-way-to-sort-an-array-by-timestamp)

My Code :

```
//where rawutimes is unsorted unix time array
console.log(rawutimes);


 // output ["1423857905", "1423611874", "1422953913", "1423499856", "1423502234", "1423502884", "1423503754", "1423510832", "1423511445", "1423514134", "1423358619", "1423583825", "1423713297", "1423713401", "1423735601", "1423772523", "1423768351", "1423817039", "1423166917", "1423446473", "1423446761", "1423835014", "1423858124", "1423857905", "1423855048", "1423852400", "1423852313", "1423852210", findIndex: function, find: function]

thesorted = rawutimes.sort(function(x, y){
    return x.timestamp - y.timestamp;
});

//printing the sorted unix time array       
console.log(thesorted);

//Output : ["1423857905", "1423852210", "1422953913", "1423499856", "1423502234", "1423502884", "1423503754", "1423510832", "1423511445", "1423514134", "1423358619", "1423583825", "1423713297", "1423713401", "1423611874", "1423772523", "1423768351", "1423817039", "1423166917", "1423446473", "1423446761", "1423835014", "1423858124", "1423857905", "1423855048", "1423852400", "1423852313", "1423735601", findIndex: function, find: function]

//Converted to Readable date format to confirm if it's sort or not?
rtimes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < rawutimes.length; i++) {
    rtime = timeConverter(thesorted[i]);
    rtimes.push(rtime);
};

//output 


//["14,Feb 2015 1:5:5", "13,Feb 2015 23:30:10", "3,Feb 2015 13:58:33", "9,Feb 2015 21:37:36", "9,Feb 2015 22:17:14", "9,Feb 2015 22:28:4", "9,Feb 2015 22:42:34", "10,Feb 2015 0:40:32", "10,Feb 2015 0:50:45", "10,Feb 2015 1:35:34", "8,Feb 2015 6:23:39", "10,Feb 2015 20:57:5", "12,Feb 2015 8:54:57", "12,Feb 2015 8:56:41", "11,Feb 2015 4:44:34", "13,Feb 2015 1:22:3", "13,Feb 2015 0:12:31", "13,Feb 2015 13:43:59", "6,Feb 2015 1:8:37", "9,Feb 2015 6:47:53", "9,Feb 2015 6:52:41", "13,Feb 2015 18:43:34", "14,Feb 2015 1:8:44", "14,Feb 2015 1:5:5", "14,Feb 2015 0:17:28", "13,Feb 2015 23:33:20", "13,Feb 2015 23:31:53", "12,Feb 2015 15:6:41"]


//result array not sorted
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you perhaps post the code you tried? It might just be a simple error on your part.

Comment: `[1,2,3].sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});` (numbers are dates are the same as seen from _sort()_ )

Comment: Post your code first what you have tried

Comment: I added the code please take a look!

Answer (score 10):

You have a list of strings, but use `.timestamp` in the sort function. Just remove it:

```js
rawutimes = ["1423857905", "1423611874", "1422953913", "1423499856", "1423502234", "1423502884", "1423503754", "1423510832", "1423511445", "1423514134", "1423358619", "1423583825", "1423713297", "1423713401", "1423735601", "1423772523", "1423768351", "1423817039", "1423166917", "1423446473", "1423446761", "1423835014", "1423858124", "1423857905", "1423855048", "1423852400", "1423852313", "1423852210"]

thesorted = rawutimes.sort(function(x, y){
    return x - y;
});

rtimes = thesorted.map(function(x) {
  return new Date(x * 1000);
});

document.write(rtimes.join("<br>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, perfectly sorted, checked in Chromium browser and Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var rawutimes = ["1423857905", "1423611874", "1422953913", "1423499856", "1423502234", "1423502884", "1423503754", "1423510832", "1423511445", "1423514134", "1423358619", "1423583825", "1423713297", "1423713401", "1423735601", "1423772523", "1423768351", "1423817039", "1423166917", "1423446473", "1423446761", "1423835014", "1423858124", "1423857905", "1423855048", "1423852400", "1423852313", "1423852210"]
console.log("Raw unix timestamps: " + rawutimes);
var formatted = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rawutimes.length; ++i) {
    var d = new Date(parseInt(rawutimes[i]) * 1000);
    formatted.push(d);
}
thesorted = formatted.sort(function (x, y) {
        return y - x;
        });
console.log("Formatted: " + thesorted);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not working i'm getting dates like Jan 1970 but actually the timestamp is Feb 2015 not sure what's wrong

Comment: Yes I forgot to multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds instead of seconds. Fixed that, please try now.

Comment: One more edit: we should sort the final array of date objects instead of the initial timestamps. Fixed that in the code.

Comment: Or, as suggested by @georg, just remove '.timestamps' from your sort. :)