# How to sort an array by timestamp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I am trying to sort this `array` by timestamp values. I want to sort them in ascending order and if any of them have an indefinite property, place it at the end. I currently have the error *Cannot read property 'first_release_date' of undefined*. How to solve this?

```js
var array = 
[
  {
    "id": 1969,
    "cover": {
      "id": 1960,
      "url": "image.jpg"
    },
    "first_release_date": 1083542400,
    "name": "Item 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 113242,
    "name": "Item 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 25076,
    "first_release_date": 1540512000,
    "name": "Item 3"
  },
  {
    "id": 1969,
    "cover": {
      "id": 1960,
      "url": "image.jpg"
    },
    "name": "Item 4"
  },
  {
    "id": 9245,
    "first_release_date": 1292976000,
    "name": "Item 5"
  }
];

Object.keys(array).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(`Before: ${array[key].name}`)
});

array.sort((a,b) => a.array.first_release_date > b.array.first_release_date);

Object.keys(array).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(`After: ${array[key].name}`)
});
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: `sort` expects a numeric return value, not a boolean. Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). It’s `a.first_release_date - b.first_release_date`. Also, there is no `array` property. Why are you adding `.array` in the middle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Fastest way to sort an array by timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555025/jquery-fastest-way-to-sort-an-array-by-timestamp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there. Only need to provide a default value for when there's no date. Also, sort requires you to return a number, at the moment you return a boolean, which will be cast to 0 or 1. Which will break the sort for the cases you want to return a negative number.

```js
var array = 
[
  {
    "id": 1969,
    "cover": {
      "id": 1960,
      "url": "image.jpg"
    },
    "first_release_date": 1083542400,
    "name": "Item 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 113242,
    "name": "Item 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 25076,
    "first_release_date": 1540512000,
    "name": "Item 3"
  },
  {
    "id": 1969,
    "cover": {
      "id": 1960,
      "url": "image.jpg"
    },
    "name": "Item 4"
  },
  {
    "id": 9245,
    "first_release_date": 1292976000,
    "name": "Item 5"
  }
];

Object.values(array).forEach((val) => {
  var d = new Date(val.first_release_date*1000).getFullYear();
  console.log(`Before: ${ val.name} ${d }`)
});

array.sort((a,b) => ( a.first_release_date || Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY ) - ( b.first_release_date || Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY ));

Object.values(array).forEach((val) => {
  var d = new Date(val.first_release_date*1000).getFullYear();
  console.log(`After: ${ val.name} ${d }`)
});

var reverse = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( array ));

reverse.sort((a,b) => ( b.first_release_date || Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY ) - ( a.first_release_date || Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY ));

console.log( reverse );
```

Comment: Wonderfull. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a question, If I want to sort them in the this order: `2018, 2010, 2004, NaN, NaN`. How can I do it? I updated your answer to show just the years. Regards.

Comment: Use the reverse: `( b.first_release_date || Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY ) - ( a.first_release_date || Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY )` So `b - a` instead of `a - b`, and then `NEGATIVE_INFINITY ` instead of `POSITIVE_INFINITY`. If the `NaN`s would not exist, just using `Array.reverse()` would also work, but that will place the `NaN`s in front.

Comment: Wow, thank you master. I will take a look on `infinity`.

Comment: It's just something to use when you need a number that will always be bigger/smaller than a number in your data, like when you need to sort. If we would just use -1, 0 or 1, then the `NaN`s would appear first in the array. Hence the need for the infinity, which basically means in this case: If no datetime, always place the item later than the other.